# Apache Kafka - Aggregation

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

Is there any concept for aggregation in Kafka like the concept of camel-aggregation .

If yes, Could anyone provide a detailed description of what it is and how to use it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Apache Camel, but you can use Kafka Streams to aggregate messaged:

I refer to the docs for now: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-aggregating

Also check out the examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/5.3.1-post/

Comment: One more help !!! Is there any way Kafka would do aggregation realtime while pushing the data to topic!!!!

Comment: Kafka does -- you might want to disable the internal record cache to get updates quicker though. Set `cache.max.bytes.buffering` to zero in your `StreamsConfig`. Cf. http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#memory-management